# Find windows program is running

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I need to add procedure in my dll project created with `Visual c++` that controls if some external `Windows GUI` program is running and start if it is not. I can start external program with `WINAPI CreateProcess`. But what is the best way to find if defined program is running?

UPD: 
Program that needs to be monitored is created with `MFC` classes and main window is dialog form. In case I use `FindWindow` I need to pass parameters `lpClassName` and  `lpWindowName`. How to know values of these parameters? Is it enough to pass executable name for both of them?

Comment: There are many possible approaches to this. What will be best depends on the scenario in detail. You omitted detail.

Comment: You really need to learn to ask about your problem, not your proposed solution. What **problem** are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

> In case I use `FindWindow` I need to pass parameters `lpClassName` and `lpWindowName`. How to know values of these parameters?

Use a tool like Spy++, Winspector, etc to see details for any window, including class name, window caption, parent/child and owner relationships, etc.

> Is it enough to pass executable name for both of them?

No.  It has to be values that are defined in the window itself.